# Why do we use Fourier series instead of Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am trying to learn about Fourier analysis. And the following question came up: While I know that the main motivation behind Fourier analysis, is to be able to represent a periodic function as a series that consists out of cosine and sine functions. I don't really understand why we do not just use normal polynomials i.e. just use the Taylor series.

I am assuming that the reason, is that, when using a Taylor series, some problems arise. But I can't figure out where the problem would be.
I would be very thankful if someone could show me an example or explain where the problem is.

Comment: The most obvious reason is that $\{e^{-inx}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is a basis for $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: Polynomials are not periodic. Also, Fourier series has weaker conditions for convergence.

Comment: For most nonperiodic function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ - in fact for most functions - the convergence of the Taylor series gets worse and worse the further you are from the center point of the Taylor expansion (exceptions to that rule are polynomials themselves). But given the Fourier series of a periodic function, there is no "center" of the expansion, and convergence properties are expressed (for the most part) uniformly.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you very much!

Comment: There are also connections to differential equations, where the properties of the Fourier series (or more often the Fourier transform, or another transform like Laplace or Z) have nicer behaviours under certain differential operators than the polynomial terms of the Taylor series.

Comment: Also, there are many, many physical phenomena that respond differently to different frequencies of sinusoids. The most obvious example is a prism, which deflects light differently by frequency, resulting in the spectrum. By expressing a general periodic function as a sum of sinusoids, we can predict how it responds to these phenomena.